# GROUP_CONCAT no trae todos los usuarios

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un error con `Group_Concat`

Si hago el query así:

```
SELECT cc.id_clasecliente, us.primer_nombre, us.primer_apellido, us.cedula,
        tu.numero_telefono AS movil, us.id_usuario, cc.asistio, cc.cancelacion_tardia,
        cc.web, cc.lista_espera, cc.id_clasefinal, cc.id_paquetecliente, pc.cantidad_clases,
        pc.fecha_vencimiento, pp.nombre_paquete, al.alerta_fisica, al.alerta_personal, ep.id_patologia, 
        ep.descripcion_patalogia as alerta_salud, pu.id_usuario
        FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc
        INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us
        ON (cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc
        ON (cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp
        ON (pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete)
        INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu
        ON (cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_patologia_usuario AS pu
        ON (cc.id_usuario = pu.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_patologia AS ep
        ON (pu.id_patologia = ep.id_patologia)
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id_usuario,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 1 THEN descripcion END) alerta_fisica,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 2 THEN descripcion END) alerta_personal
                FROM ec_alerta
                WHERE id_tipoalerta IN (1,2)
                GROUP BY id_usuario) al
        ON (cc.id_usuario = al.id_usuario)
        WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = '" . $Id_clase . "'
        AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 2
        ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
```

Me trae los datos así, me pica al primer usuario en dos si consigue dos patologías en `ec_patologias`. Eso no puede pasar porque necesito las dos patologías en la misma fila

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Trate de colocarle un Group_Concat a ep.descripcion_patalogia

```
SELECT cc.id_clasecliente, us.primer_nombre, us.primer_apellido, us.cedula,
        tu.numero_telefono AS movil, us.id_usuario, cc.asistio, cc.cancelacion_tardia,
        cc.web, cc.lista_espera, cc.id_clasefinal, cc.id_paquetecliente, pc.cantidad_clases,
        pc.fecha_vencimiento, pp.nombre_paquete, al.alerta_fisica, al.alerta_personal, ep.id_patologia, 
        group_concat(ep.descripcion_patalogia separator ', ') as `alerta_salud`, pu.id_usuario
        FROM ec_clientes_clases AS cc
        INNER JOIN ec_usuario AS us
        ON (cc.id_usuario = us.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquete_cliente AS pc
        ON (cc.id_paquetecliente = pc.id_paquetecliente)
        LEFT JOIN ec_paquetes AS pp
        ON (pp.id_paquete = pc.id_paquete)
        INNER JOIN ec_telefonos_usuario AS tu
        ON (cc.id_usuario = tu.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_patologia_usuario AS pu
        ON (cc.id_usuario = pu.id_usuario)
        LEFT JOIN ec_patologia AS ep
        ON (pu.id_patologia = ep.id_patologia)
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  id_usuario,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 1 THEN descripcion END) alerta_fisica,
                        MAX(CASE WHEN id_tipoalerta = 2 THEN descripcion END) alerta_personal
                FROM ec_alerta
                WHERE id_tipoalerta IN (1,2)
                GROUP BY id_usuario) al
        ON (cc.id_usuario = al.id_usuario)
        WHERE cc.id_clasefinal = '" . $Id_clase . "'
        AND tu.id_tipotelefono = 2
        ORDER BY cc.id_clasecliente ASC;
```

Y no trajo el segundo usuario, simplemente lo ignoró. Me gustaría saber que estoy haciendo mal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Intenta agregando `GROUP BY cc.id_clasecliente`

Comment: En donde lo puedo colocar?

Comment: Antes del `ORDER BY`

Comment: Eso lo arregló, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se da por que has omitido indicar como agrupar los registros.

#### Solución:

Agregar `GROUP BY cc.id_clasecliente` antes del `ORDER BY`

---

Referencias:

- [GROUP BY - MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)